# The lion of a man is okay?

Tags: word-usage

I think that **a lion of a man** is like:

> A man is like a lion (brave)

What about

> "the lion of a man"? Does this mean that *a man* has the lion?

ps. a friend of a man : a man is like a friend (a lion of a man: a man is like a lion), correct?

Comment: "A lion of a man" is OK, but we would never say "The lion of a man". The man is being compared to lions in general, not a particular lion.

Comment: And yes, "the lion of a man" means "a man's lion".

Comment: How does "the lion of a man" differ from "the lion of a man's"?

Comment: In answer to your PS - Certain  phrases such as _a giant of a man_ are idiomatic, but we can't make an expression  like that out of just any noun. _A friend of a man_ doesn't mean anything, except in a sentence like "I've found out that my new neighbour is a friend of a man I used to work with."

Comment: @KateBunting In "a lion of a man", the article applies to the man, not the lion. I see nothing wrong with "the lion of a man" if said about a specific man who has already been identified.

Comment: @Astralbee - H'mm - "that lion of a man", perhaps. I think we would say "X is a lion of a man", but we wouldn't use the phrase in a subsequent reference to him.

Comment: @KateBunting Your two diametrically opposite comments can't both be right. If you can say "that", which points to a specific person, then the article has nothing to do with a specific lion or lions in general. If I can say "I hope the mess of a comment that you made gets deleted" then I can say "the lion of a man that is Astralbee is correct".

Comment: @Astralbee - Well, okay, perhaps I was incorrect in saying that _the lion of a man_ refers to a specific lion, but I still think it is unidiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you may be confusing "idiomatic" with *an idiom*. We talk a lot about things being 'idiomatic' on here, which basically just means the way *most* people would say something. It doesn't mean it is the only acceptable way. This is only "less idiomatic" in the sense that the idiom, as written, is "**a** lion of a man", like the idiom "**a** bird in the hand...". But if someone referred to something as "**the proverbial** bird in the hand", you would recognise the idiom and the use of grammar would be absolutely fine.

Comment: @Astralbee - Thank you, I do _not_ need to be taught the meaning of _idiomatic_! I meant exactly what I said.

Answer (score 2):

It would be far more common to say that someone is "**a** lion of a man", using the *indefinite* article, for the reason that they are not likely to be the *only* man comparable to a lion. For the reason that it is more common, it likely sounds much more idiomatic to a native speaker. As a 'saying' (or 'idiom'), most people will be more familiar with it using the indefinite article, but that doesn't mean you can't use it with a definite article.

Ultimately, the article 'a' applies to a man, *who is being compared to the lion*. There is no lion! Therefore, if the context makes it appropriate for you to say "*the* man" (ie. if talking about a specific man who has already been identified), there can be nothing wrong with saying "*the* lion of a man".

For example:

> John was huge and muscular. I watched as the lion of a man made light work of lifting the weights.

You'll see the expression has also been used with the definite article [here](https://lithuaniatribune.com/bukovsky/).

Comment: Thx. There is two a (A lion of A man). Is it okay ? I thought first A referred to lion.

Comment: @brandon It's absolutely fine that there are two articles. "A lion of a man" is an idiomatic way of saying "a man like a lion". It is no different to saying "a whopper of a beefburger", or "a fine specimen of a woman".

Comment: According to you, "first a or the" refers to "man", then "lion of" is "like lion"or "lion of a"? In this case, 'of' is equal to 'like' execpt that we need 'hyphen': lion-like

Comment: @Brandon Not really. If I said "that is **a** fine example of a cake", what am I talking about? An example? Or a cake? There's only a cake. In the OP's example, **there is no lion**! There's only a man.

Comment: It's very interesting to know first time in my life the first "a" or "the" refers to "a man" especially "man".

Comment: the 'of' in "lion of "is like the 'of' in "kind of" or "sort of"?

Comment: @brandon No, not exactly the same. For example, if you wanted to say "a fine example of a cake" about more than one cake, you'd have to pluralise both elements and say "fine example**s** of cake**s**". But with 'kind of' or 'sort of' you wouldn't - 'battenburg is **a** kind of cake', or 'battenburg**s** are **a** kind of cake'.